# How do I alter an existing text file to add new data after a specific line using Python

Tags: python, paradox-scripting

So I am looking to create a script to make a mod for a game using Python. The script will need to copy all files from a directory to another directory, then alter those files to add a new attribute after a specific line. The issue I am having is that this game uses custom coding based on json formatting in a txt file. I know how to do most of this, however, adding the new data is not something I can get to work.

My end goal will be to be able to do this to any file, so other mod authors can use it to add the data to their mods without needing to do it manually. I also want to try to make this script do more advanced things, but that is another goal that can wait till I get this bit working.

Sample data:
The line I need to add is `position_priority = ###`. The `###` will be different based on what the building does (building categories).

Sample code I need to alter:

```
building_name_number = {
    base_build_time = 60
    base_cap_amount = 1
    
    category = pop_assembly
   
    <more code>
}
```

I need to put the new data just after `building_name_number`, however this exact name will be unique, the only thing that will always be the same is that it will start with `building`. So regex is what I have been trying to use, but I have never dealt with regex so I cant get it to work.

My Current code:

```py
if testingenabled:
    workingdir = R"E:/Illusives-Mods/Stellaris/Building Sorting"
    pattern = "^building_"
    Usortingindex = sortingindex["sorting_pop_assembly"]
    print(f"Testing Perameters: Index: {Usortingindex}, Version: {__VERSION__}, Working DIR: {workingdir}")
    # os.chdir(stellaris_buildings_path)
    os.chdir(workingdir)
    for file in os.listdir(workingdir):

        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, "*.txt"):
            
            print("File found")

            with open(file, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as openfiledata:
                alllines = openfiledata.read()
                for line in alllines:
                    if line == re.match(r'(^building_)', line, re.M):
                        print("found match")
                        # print(f"{sorting_attrib}{Usortingindex}")
                        # print("position_priority = 200")
                        openfiledata.write("\n" + sorting_attrib + Usortingindex + "\n")

            break
```

I am not getting any errors with this code. But it doesnt work
I am using Python `3.9.6`.

EDIT:
This code is before the script

```
    allow = {
        hidden_trigger = {
            OR = {
                owner = { is_ai = no }
                NAND = {
                    free_district_slots = 0
                    free_building_slots <= 1
                    free_housing <= 0
                    free_jobs <= 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is after

```
        allow = {
            hidden_trigger = {
                OR = {
                    owner = {
                        is_ai = false
                    }
                    NAND = {
                        free_district_slots = 0
                        free_building_slots = {
                            value = 1
                            operand = <=
                        }
                        free_housing = {
                            value = 0
                            operand = <=
                        }
                        free_jobs = {
                            value = 0
                            operand = <=
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The output must be the same as the input, at least in terms of the operators

Comment: better read all data to Python, add value in python, and save all data back to file. And all it would be simpler if you would keep it as JSON - you would read it to Python dictionary, add elements to this dictionary and write back this dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you would keep it as JSON then you could read all to Python (to get ti as dictionary), search and add items in dictionary, and write back to JSON new dictionary.

```
text = '''{
"building_name_number": {
    "base_build_time": 60,
    "base_cap_amount": 1,
    "category": "pop_assembly"
},
"building_other": {}
}'''

import json

data = json.loads(text)

for key in data.keys():
    if key.startswith('building_'):
        data[key]["position_priority"] = 'some_value'
        
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Result:

```
{
    "building_name_number": {
        "base_build_time": 60,
        "base_cap_amount": 1,
        "category": "pop_assembly",
        "position_priority": "some_value"
    },
    "building_other": {
        "position_priority": "some_value"
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the file format. Its a custom formatting. There are other issues like upgrade paths and conversion notes that I would need to exclude.

Comment: if you use custom format then you will have to write all on your own. But I would do in simillar way - read all data to Pyton, update data in Python, write all data back to file,

Comment: The issue is that this is for a game, not for my own program. Otherwise I would just use json or xml. This formatting is easy to mod with, but seems to be very hard to manipulate with scripts :P. Ive tried alot of things to get it to work, but nothing is working. Have any suggestions? Regex and startswith dont work with this (at least not if I want to write to the next line after a match)

Comment: I would first write script which read all data and create Python dictionary - `parser`, and which can write it back in expected format. But maybe it would be simpler to replace some elements in text - to create text more similar to JSON - and use `dirtyjson` to convert it to Python dictionary. `dirtyjson` can load `JSON` even if it has some mistakes.

Comment: see module [paradox-reader](https://github.com/joshnygaard/paradox-reader) - it seems it can read your file and convert to JSON. But it doesn't have function to write JSON back to your file - but maybe this part can be simpler

Answer (score 0):

I found module [paradox-reader](https://github.com/joshnygaard/paradox-reader) which can convert this file format to JSON file.

Using code from file [paradoxReader.py](https://github.com/joshnygaard/paradox-reader/blob/master/paradoxReader.py) I created example which can convert string to Python dictionary, add some value and convert to something similar to original file. But this may need to add more code in `encode()`

```
import json
import re

def decode(data):#, no_json):

    data = re.sub(r'#.*', '', data) # Remove comments
    data = re.sub(r'(?<=^[^\"\n])*(?<=[0-9\.\-a-zA-Z])+(\s)(?=[0-9\.\-a-zA-Z])+(?=[^\"\n]*$)', '\n', data, flags=re.MULTILINE) # Seperate one line lists
    data = re.sub(r'[\t ]', '', data) # Remove tabs and spaces

    definitions = re.findall(r'(@\w+)=(.+)', data) # replace @variables with value

    if definitions:
        for definition in definitions:
            data = re.sub(r'^@.+', '', data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
            data = re.sub(definition[0], definition[1], data)

    data = re.sub(r'\n{2,}', '\n', data) # Remove excessive new lines
    data = re.sub(r'\n', '', data, count=1)  # Remove the first new line
    data = re.sub(r'{(?=\w)', '{\n', data) # reformat one-liners
    data = re.sub(r'(?<=\w)}', '\n}', data) # reformat one-liners
    data = re.sub(r'^[\w-]+(?=[\=\n><])', r'"\g<0>"', data, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # Add quotes around keys
    data = re.sub(r'([^><])=', r'\1:', data)  # Replace = with : but not >= or <=
    data = re.sub(r'(?<=:)(?!-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)(?!\".*\")[^{\n]+', r'"\g<0>"', data)  # Add quotes around string values
    data = re.sub(r':"yes"', ':true', data) # Replace yes with true
    data = re.sub(r':"no"', ':false', data)  # Replace no with false
    data = re.sub(r'([<>]=?)(.+)', r':{"value":\g<2>,"operand":"\g<1>"}', data) # Handle < > >= <=
    data = re.sub(r'(?<![:{])\n(?!}|$)', ',', data)  # Add commas
    data = re.sub(r'\s', '', data) # remove all white space
    data = re.sub(r'{(("[a-zA-Z_]+")+)}', r'[\g<1>]', data) # make lists
    data = re.sub(r'""', r'","', data) # Add commas to lists
    data = re.sub(r'{("\w+"(,"\w+")*)}', r'[\g<1>]', data)
    data = re.sub(r'((\"hsv\")({\d\.\d{1,3}(,\d\.\d{1,3}){2}})),', r'{\g<2>:\g<3>},', data) # fix hsv objects
    data = re.sub(r':{([^}{:]*)}', r':[\1]', data) # if there's no : between list elements need to replace {} with []
    data = re.sub(r'\[(\w+)\]', r'"\g<1>"', data)
    data = re.sub(r'\",:{', '":{', data) # Fix user_empire_designs
    data = '{' + data + '}'

    return json.loads(data)

def encode(data):
    text = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    text = text[2:-2]
    text = text.replace('"', '').replace(':', ' =').replace(',', '')
    return text

# ----------

text = '''building_name_number = {
    base_build_time = 60
    base_cap_amount = 1
    
    category = pop_assembly
}'''

data = decode(text)
data['building_name_number']['new_item'] = 123

text = encode(data)
print(text)
```

Result:

```
    building_name_number = {
        base_build_time = 60
        base_cap_amount = 1
        category = pop_assembly
        new_item = 123
    }
```

Comment: Another issue I found is that it converts {} to [] if there is no key:value pair, and I cant seem to reverse it in the encode code...

Comment: JSON uses `{}` only for dictionares - and for lists it use `[]`. It can't use `{}` for list.

Comment: I am aware of that. I am asking how to revert that conversion as the code does not use `[ ]` at all.

Comment: I also need to revert the operator conversion in decode as that is another place where the code differs

Comment: it is normal text - you can use another `replace()` to change elements in text. But it would be simpler if in question you would show example data which makes problem.

Comment: I have added more code to the OP